# How to get the agrument after the command using GETOPTS in BASH

Tags: bash, getopts

Example of script usage

`./myscript --p 1984 --n someName`

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts :npr opt 
do
   case $opt in
     n ) echo name= ???                ;;
     p ) echo port=  ???               ;;
     r ) echo robot= "Something"       ;;
     ? ) echo  "Useage: -p [#]"        ;;
  esac
done
```

How to I access the argument following the command option?

Moreover, if i type: `./myscript --p 1985` I would like to know how ot echo 1985 back and work with that argument.

Comment: Of course, you actually invoke the command as `myscript -p 1984 -n someName`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bash, see `help getopts`: "When an option requires an argument, getopts places that argument into the shell variable **OPTARG**."

```
usage() { echo "Usage: $(basename $0) -n name -p port -r"; exit; }

while getopts :n:p:r opt   # don't forget the colons for opts that take an arg
do
   case $opt in
     n ) name="$OPTARG" ;;
     p ) port="$OPTARG" ;;
     r ) robot=chicken  ;;
     ? ) usage ;;
  esac
done
shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))

echo "the name is $name"
echo "the port is $port"
```

---

I'm sure you could google around for a solution to parse options in bash. Here's a couple minutes' effort:

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() { echo foo; exit; }

while [[ $1 == -* ]]; do
  case "$1" in 
    --) shift 1; break ;;
    -p|--p|--port) port="$2"; shift 2;;
    -n|--n|--name) name="$2"; shift 2;;
    *) echo "unknown option: $1"; usage;;
  esac
done

echo "the name is $name"
echo "the port is $port"
echo "the rest of the args are:"; ( IFS=,; echo "$*" )
```

And a test,

```
$ bash longopts.sh --port 1234 --bar a b c
unknown option: --bar
foo
$ bash longopts.sh --port 1234 a b c
the name is
the port is 1234
the rest of the args are:
a,b,c
```

Comment: what does the shift $(( OPTIND - 1 )) do?

Comment: That allows you to remove the options that you just processed from the positional parameters, so you can access any additional arguments from the command line.

Comment: Note, with getopts, you cannot use double dashes (`--p 1984`). You must use a single dash (`-p 1984`)

Comment: Is it possible to --port then? using getopts? is there anyway to supply a long command and using the -- prefix also

Comment: You cannot use getopts for long-style options. Answer updated